# ValueError: Inconsistent Shapes Error in Scikit Learn Train_Test Split

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm preparing to run some predictions on a csv document comparing job descriptions to salary outcomes. I've split the data set into training and test where features is what I'm working with and target is what I'm predicting. When I go to print and confirm that these records were separated properly I get the following error: ValueError: Inconsistent Shapes

My code and the resulting error follow:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

# create posting & label list
postList = []
labelList = []
filename = '\Users\yantezia.patrick\Downloads\Postings.csv'
csvFile = csv.reader(open(filename, 'r'), delimiter=",")
for row in csvFile:
    postList.append(row[2])
    labelList.append(row[10]) #appending specific columns to specific list #these willbe labels

# remove first row
postList = postList[1:] #clearing out the header rows
labelList = labelList[1:]

temp = np.array([float(i) for i in labelList])
med = np.median(temp)
for i, val in enumerate(labelList):
    if float(val) >= med:
        labelList[i] = 1
    else:
        labelList[i] = 0

# subset list
postList = postList[:100]
labelList = labelList[:100]
print postList[:2]

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd

# create term matrix
cv = CountVectorizer(lowercase=True, stop_words='english', ngram_range=(1,3), min_df=10)
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(lowercase=True, stop_words='english', ngram_range=(1,3), min_df=10)

tf_dm = cv.fit_transform(postList)
tfidf_dm = tfidf.fit_transform(postList)

pd.DataFrame(tfidf_dm.toarray(),index=postList,columns=tfidf.get_feature_names()).head(10)

tfidf.get_feature_names()
tm = tm.toarray()
print tf_dm
tm = cv.fit(postList)
print tm.vocabulary_
print tf_dm.shape
print tfidf_dm.shape

#add labels to word vector
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

features_train1 = train_test_split(tf_dm, labels, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
features_test1 = train_test_split(tf_dm, labels, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
target_train1 = train_test_split(tf_dm, labels, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
target_test1 = train_test_split(tf_dm, labels, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

features_train2 = train_test_split(tfidf_dm, labels, test_size=0.33, random_state=7)
features_test2 = train_test_split(tfidf_dm, labels, test_size=0.33, random_state=7)
target_train2 = train_test_split(tfidf_dm, labels, test_size=0.33, random_state=7)
target_test2 = train_test_split(tfidf_dm, labels, test_size=0.33, random_state=7)

print np.sum(target_train1)
print np.sum(target_test1)
print target_train1
print target_test1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-53ecd8559f48> in <module>()
----> 1 print np.sum(target_train1)
      2 print np.sum(target_test1)
      3 print target_train1
      4 print target_test1

C:\Users\yantezia.patrick\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.pyc in sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
   1707         except AttributeError:
   1708             return _methods._sum(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
-> 1709                                 out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
   1710         # NOTE: Dropping the keepdims parameters here...
   1711         return sum(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out)

C:\Users\yantezia.patrick\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.pyc in _sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     23 def _sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
     24     return um.add.reduce(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
---> 25                             out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
     26 
     27 def _prod(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):

C:\Users\yantezia.patrick\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.pyc in __add__(self, other)
    340         elif isspmatrix(other):
    341             if (other.shape != self.shape):
--> 342                 raise ValueError("inconsistent shapes")
    343 
    344             return self._binopt(other,'_plus_')

ValueError: inconsistent shapes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please explain what you are trying to do?
The definitions of `features_train1`, `features_test1`, `target_train1` and `target_test` are the same. As you fixed the random state, they will all have the same content.
Have you tried to look at what any of these are?
Please look at [the documentation of train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html#sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split).
`features_train1` is a tuple, where the first two elements are a split of `tf_dm` and the second two are a split of `labels`.

What you most likely meant to do was

```
features_train1, features_test1, labels_train1, labels_test1 = train_test_split(tf_dm, labels, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```